# Why dev-dependencies cannot be optional?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

As it's clearly mentioned [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html), dev-dependencies cannot be optional. What is the underlying reason for that?

This is an example of where the optional dev-dependency could be useful and important: Suppose you have a package A that needs a package B for the testing purpose. However, when you test the package A, in some cases, you specify a particular feature:
`cargo test --package A --features "F1"`
It would then seem to be legitimate that you have the option of specifying the dev-dependency to B differently when the feature "F1" is selected. But if your dev-dependency is already pulled in (non-optionally) you seem to have no control over that!

Comment: If a dependency is optional anyway, can't you make it a normal dependency instead of a dev dependency? You can then only enable it when running the tests. (This isn't meant as an explanation why dev dependencies can't be optional, but it may be an acceptable solution for your use case.)

Comment: Unconditional dev-deps are [a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5133) with Cargo. There hasn’t been much progress in that direction lately so perhaps you could add a comment detailing you use case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks for the idea. However, converting dev dependencies to normal dependencies, in my case, leads to getting cyclic dependencies.

Comment: One use case for this would be a scenario where you have a test sub-crate whose sole purpose is to test a particular feature where if that feature isn't present it doesn't make sense to even compile the sub-crate